# Displaying all the Android device active processes through Java code

Tags: java, android, shell

I have my code working fine for Android device 5 but when I test the same code for Android device 6 - it is not fetching all the processes to be displayed on my application console. I am able to get all the running processes in command pompt by running adb shell top -n 1; but, failing to get all the running processes in my application console by running my code. Please me know if there is anything that I am missing that is not getting all the running processes onto my console.

Comment: You need to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to get help with this sort of problem. Please edit your question to supply your code, explain what your "application console" is, and explain the output that you are seeing in this console when you run your code.

Comment: What is the best way to fetch all the process details of android device 6?